# Не создаётся slash_commands() | discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не создаётся slash_commands() discord.py
и если кому не трудно почему многие топят за disnake

Comment: С чего вы решили что он не создаётся?

Comment: @ΝNL993, видимо, из-за того, что редактор не подсказывает...

Comment: с того что в редакторе нету + выдаёт ошибку если ввожу

Answer (score 0):

`discord.py` - у меня работает подобный код для создания слэш-команд:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.tree.sync()

@bot.tree.command(name='hello', description='Hello World!')
def example(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Привет пользователь!')
```

В качестве рекомендации могу сказать, что дискорд поддерживает типизацию переменных через модуль `typing` (чрезвычайно широкие возможности для подсказок пользователям)

В качестве предупреждения могу сказать - что тут на вход подаётся объект [Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction:%7E:text=by%20the%20user.-,Interaction,-%C2%B6), а не [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#context:%7E:text=pass%20this%20check.-,Context,-%C2%B6).

Comment: `bot.tree.sync()` перезаписывает все существующие слэш-команды, так что будет аккуратны при запуске нескольких экземпляров бота.